# How to get the section a task is in?

Tags: asana

Is there a way to get the section a task is/was in from the API.

I see how we could use the entire project Json to figure it out. But once a task is completed it jumps to the top of the page. Wondering how to figure out what section it was in if it's complete.

Comment: are you looking for the `assignee_status` or something beyond that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the API response we don't make tasks "jump" to the top - the position is kept in priority order, and should still be located under the section it belongs to.

Of course, this isn't a terribly elegant way to do it. We're currently considering how to handle Sections in the API in a better way, but we don't have a concrete plan for it yet and it's not yet on the actual roadmap.

But in the meantime, you should be able to get the project, as you said, and just look at which Section (i.e. a task that ends in ":") the tasks come after, and you're set!